# convert the input to link back with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the jquery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.a0').click(function(){
    $('#url0,#url1').val($(this).text()).show();
    $(this).hide();
});

$('.a0 a').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});


});
```

the HTML :

```
<div style="padding:0 !important">
    <div class="a0" style="padding: 0px ! important; display: none;">
        <a href="http://dasda.cas">dasda.cas</a>
    </div>
    <input type="text" value="dasda.cas" class="mandatory1" id="url1" style="" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

first it's link then when i click on the div it converts to input to make edit then when i click out of it or tab need to be converted to link again.

UPDATE:
**MY need is** : to convert the text to a link after editing it.
it's a check out form, the last step of the check out, so i have instant edit ajax, by default it's a link with that hidden input that you can see, and i need after the edit to be a link too because after editing it remains a text not a link.

Comment: are you kidding me ? i'm asking a normal question !!!!

Comment: You will never be able to follow that link. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: really don't understand why closed ! it's an URL input with instant edit, and i need to be link, not only text because it's an url input, but at the same time to be able to edit, and it's working, only that when i click out or tab remain text and i need it to be back link

Comment: but Upper... if once you edited your nice link... you want to click it, that you'll never be able to click/follow that link cause it will over and over open the input, right? Explain better your needs and the question might be reopened...

Comment: Use also normal punctuation. :|

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan let me explain more, it's a cart with an order and there's a link to the website of the client, so maybe in the filling in info the url was posted by him wrong, i have in the final step of the check out ajax instant edit, but this instant edit is only for text and i need the url input to be clickable, by the code above it's a link with a hidden input, so when you click link go to page, out side of link edit it in the hidden input but when finished it remains a text, and i need it to be a link again with the hidden input :)

Comment: _"i'm asking a normal question"_ - You didn't actually ask a question, and what you did say was kind of unclear. If I understand you correctly, your link is not used for navigation, its sole purpose is to display data and convert to/from an input that lets you edit that data? (So the objection @RokoC.Buljan raised about not being able to follow the link doesn't matter?)

Comment: @nnnnnn and this was the problem? really? ok, next time i will ask, i thought that explaining what i want to do and not succeed will be enough

Comment: Reedit your Q please it's still not understandable after your comment. or... rather post again a new - better explained Q.

Comment: _"I thought that explaining what i want to do and not succeed will be enough"_ - You didn't make it clear how much of your requirement was already implemented by the code you showed, leaving us to try to figure out both what you were trying to ask and what the potential answer(s) might be. Next time consider also posting a demo on http://jsfiddle.net, so we can see the current behaviour for ourselves.

Comment: @nnnnnn please check this: http://jsfiddle.net/BSGS6/5/ , the URL field

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan please check this: jsfiddle.net/BSGS6/5 , the URL field

Comment: Is this the behaviour you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/BSGS6/7/

Comment: @nnnnnn yes perfect :) but need to do when click out side the link not on the link for editing, and when click on the div of the link then edit, how can i make this ?

Comment: You need to give your users something concrete to click on - "outside the link" is too vague: you're expecting your users to somehow guess which empty space to click on. Look at how Stack Overflow comment editing works - there's an "edit" link that appears next to the comment when you hover...

Comment: @nnnnnn you are right, but all other input fields (name ..etc) are like this so i think the client won't be confuse, correct? also can't edit now all fields to appear the edit word next to all fields, can't i make it when click out side the like but in the same row (div) to make the edit? instead of clicking on the link ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to convert the textbox back to link

```
$('#url0,#url1').blur(function() {
    $(this).prev().show().find('a').attr(this.value);
    $(this).hide();
});
​
```